# Integration problem with full derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, line-integrals

I am trying to find out what type of integration is used to solve this problem and what are the rules behind it. I am sorry, if this question is quite basic, but I do not study Mathematics.

[The homework problem and its answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLzSh.png)

The translation of the text: Test, if this differential form is a full differential. Calculate the finite change dv integrating this differential form from the start of coordinates to the point (a,b) along two tajectories: (0,0)->(a,0)->(a.b) and (0,0)->(0,b)->(a,b).

I would be extremely thankful for any kind of help!

Best regards,

Austėja

Comment: Yes, this is a line integral. In general, the integral from one point to another will depend on the path you follow. Those that give you path independence are conservative vector fields or, in "differential" language, exact differentials.

Comment: @TedShifrin, thank you very much for the answer provided!